# Extension for Specflow in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, specflow

I have a set of tests using specflow on Visual Studio, some of them have steps that looks like:

```
Given the data in file /foo/bar/data.txt
```

I would like to implement a Visual Studio extension so I can click on /foo/bar/data.txt and get the file opened.

I had a vague idea of using something like a Visual Studio text adorn, but I really don't know if there is a simpler way. Moreover, I'm looking for a solution that works in Visual Studio 2013 and above, and adorns are not supported in older versions as far as I know. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to create a new menu entry with a Visual Studio Add-in, this way when you click in a line, and choose this menu option, you can execute an action (read and parse the line and open the file). This can be done as follows:

File->New Project->Other Types -> Extensibility -> Visual Studio Add-in, and the implement IDTCommandTarget

```
Commands2 commands = (Commands2)_applicationObject.Commands;
object[] contextGUIDS = new object[] { };
CommandBars cmdBars = (CommandBars)(_applicationObject.CommandBars);
CommandBar vsBarProject = cmdBars["Code Window"];

scenarioCommand = commands.AddNamedCommand2(_addInInstance, "OpenScenario", "Open scenario", "Open scenario data", true);
scenarioCommand.AddControl(vsBarProject);
```

Then in the Exec method, just read the line, get the file path, and:

```
Process.Start(resource)
```

And of course, just show the menu option if is a specFlow file in the QueryStatus method:

```
dynamic docName = _applicationObject.ActiveDocument.FullName;
if (CmdName == OpenScenarioCmd && !((string)docName).EndsWith(".feature"))
{
    StatusOption = (vsCommandStatus)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;
}
else if (CmdName == OpenScenarioCmd)
{
    StatusOption = (vsCommandStatus)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported | vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
}
```

It's not perfect, because you have to show a menu, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefix the file path with file:// it will become a clickable link. Replace spaces with "%20" as you would with any URL.

[image: Sample screenshot]

I know that's not the answer to the question you are asking, but maybe you don't need to implement an extension?

Comment: yes, this should work, but I can't change the way files are referenced via relative paths, because these files are versioned, so they can be in different base paths. I have found a solution, I will answer myself